# C# Socket: how to simulate real LDAP client connecting?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, networking, ldap

I have an error condition in my connection handling code. This error causes my server to freeze, but RANDOMLY, on some requests. It's important the requests are identical. Let's say 25% of them causes the server to freeze.

Here's the catch: the server freezes when and only when the first **TEST** request is made. On infinite number of subsequent **TEST** requests it won't fail... It's very important: it happens only when testing with my unit test.

My test just runs `DirectoryEntry` query. It creates `n` `DirectoryEntry` objects, queries them, then calls `Close` on each one, then repeats the procedure `m` times.

If it fails, it fails on first query.

BUT THEN if I connect real LDAP client like LdapAdmin, it behaves completely different! The chance the server will crash is very high, over 50%. Obviously, the real client does something differently while connecting, and obviously, even **my C# test code also does that crashing thing, but only for the first time. My subsequent test queries do not test the server at all. They have zero efficiency against detecting "client connecting" freeze.**

Now I test it by manually running my test "exe" file several times. Probability of catching the freeze is nearly 100% after 8 tries. Now I want my unit test to do that for me - do the offending action let's say 8 times and fail if it freezes once.

Unfortunately - the state of connecting client is different on application start and on subsequent calls. My question is WHAT EXACTLY is different? I tested it's not the server under the test. I can crash it anytime by connecting to it from external client. First attempt - success, client connected, client can try to DDOS my server, good luck, it doesn't happen. But then I try to connect again, server dies. I try to simulate this behavior in my test, but I fail. Either I detect crash on first attempt, or I get infinite number of successful connections. I need a way to truly reset my test client, so they would behave like a new client app connecting to my server for the first time. `Close` and `Dispose` methods of `DirectoryEntry` do not achieve that goal, or something else is involved.

No code sample, because `DirectoryEntry` query is a one-liner. My test should just execute such query, but should also disconnect afterwards forgetting it ever connected to the server. I want each `DirectoryEntry` query be as fresh and first as when the application is started.

BTW, I already found the cause of this particular freeze, now I want such case to be detectable by my unit test to avoid similar issues when the code is changed.

Another weird finding: When I try to connect 10k clients to my server - it passes... or fails on the first attempt.

**Also tried:**
I waited for `Disposed` event of `DirectoryEntry` objects. Didn't help. Still no joy. To catch the freeze I must run the same test several times.

Tried to dispose all objects including the tested server and recreate them multiple times during the test. Still no joy. Either fails on start, or doesn't fail no matter how many times this test is iterated.